# I get the error "error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory" when I try to build a project on Qt

Tags: c++, unix, opencl, qt-creator, qmake

I am trying to run the "Valar" benchmark applications on my system through Qt Creator and am getting errors when I build the code:

https://github.com/Frinhard/valar-bench

I typed the command: `autoreconf -ivf` and got the following output:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
aclocal: couldn't open directory `m4': No such file or directory
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

All my errors were connected to the file m4 so **I created an empty directory and named it m4**. After that I was able to run the command `autoreconf --install` and I no longer kept getting the same error. Moreover, Makefile.in was also generated along with many other files.

The link shows the state of the directory after I ran `autoreconf --install`:

[image: Files after the command]

I ran the command `qmake --project` on the command line and the `.pro` file was generated.

I opened the newly generated .pro file in Qt Creator and linked the OpenCL libraries in addition to the other OpenCL files in the "bin" directory.

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/ -lOpenCL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 $$PWD/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64

DISTFILES += \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/amd/CLSource/createDescriptors_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/amd/CLSource/getOrientation_kernels.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/amd/CLSource/hessianDet_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/amd/CLSource/integralImage_kernels.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/amd/CLSource/nearestNeighbor_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/amd/CLSource/nonMaxSuppression_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/amd/CLSource/normalizeDescriptors_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/nvidia/CLSource/createDescriptors_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/nvidia/CLSource/getOrientation_kernels.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/nvidia/CLSource/hessianDet_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/nvidia/CLSource/integralImage_kernels.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/nvidia/CLSource/nearestNeighbor_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/nvidia/CLSource/nonMaxSuppression_kernel.cl \
    ../../Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/bin/nvidia/CLSource/normalizeDescriptors_kernel.cl
```

I got the following errors after clicking on `Build`:

```
    17:27:13: Running steps for project valar-bench...
    17:27:13: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
    17:27:13: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
    Makefile:941: warning: overriding commands for target `eventlist.o'
    Makefile:875: warning: ignoring old commands for target `eventlist.o'
    Makefile:1014: warning: overriding commands for target `main.o'
    Makefile:960: warning: ignoring old commands for target `main.o'
    g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../valar-bench -I. -I../valar-bench -I../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc -I../valar-bench/fir -I../valar-bench/clhaptic/libanalysis-devices -I../valar-bench/clhaptic/libprofiler -I../valar-bench/clhaptic/libtopology -I../valar-bench/clhaptic/librules -I../valar-bench/clhaptic/libinterceptor -I../valar-bench/clsurf/src -I../valar-bench/particles/Common/Base -I../valar-bench/particles/Common/Math -I../valar-bench/particles/TestBed/Demos -I../valar-bench/particles/Common/Utils -I../valar-bench/particles/TestBed -I../valar-bench/particles/Common/DeviceUtils -I../valar-bench/particles/Common/Geometry -I../valar-bench/particles -I/root/Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 -I/root/Downloads/valar-bench/valar-bench/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/include -I/opt/QtInstallation/5.6/gcc_64/include -I/opt/QtInstallation/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/QtInstallation/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/QtInstallation/5.6/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o FIR_tapchange.o ../valar-bench/fir/FIR_tapchange.cpp
    ../valar-bench/fir/FIR_tapchange.cpp:16:19: error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from ../valar-bench/fir/FIR_tapchange.cpp:18:
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:40: error: 'cl_device_id' was not declared in this scope
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:42: error: variable or field 'ad_sync' declared void
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:42: error: 'cl_command_queue' was not declared in this scope
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:46: error: 'cl_mem' does not name a type
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:48: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'cl_int' with no type
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:48: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'status'
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:50: error: 'cl_device_id' has not been declared
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:52: error: variable or field 'ad_setKernelArg' declared void
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:52: error: 'cl_kernel' was not declared in this scope
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:52: error: expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:52: error: expected primary-expression before 'size'
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:53: error: expected primary-expression before 'void'
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:59: error: 'cl_program' does not name a type
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:63: error: 'cl_program' does not name a type
    ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libmisc/opencl_utils.h:76: error: 'cl_platform_id' was not declared in this scope
    In file included from ../valar-bench/fir/FIR_tapchange.cpp:19:
    ../valar-bench/fir/FIR_tapchange.h:12: error: 'cl_command_queue' does not name a type
    In file included from ../valar-bench/clhaptic/libanalysis-devices/analysis-devices.h:6,
.                    
.
.
.
.
    make: *** [FIR_tapchange.o] Error 1
    17:27:13: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
    Error while building/deploying project valar-bench (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 GCC 64bit)
    When executing step "Make"
    17:27:13: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

The following is the information regarding qmake that I have:

```
Qmake version: 1.07a (Qt 3.3.8b)
Qmake is free software from Trolltech ASA.
```

Please guide me in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem got fixed when I changed my method of setting the paths.

In my question, I had set the paths in the following way:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/ -lOpenCL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 $$PWD/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64
```

I set the paths again in the following way and the errors got fixed:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/ -lOpenCL

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/\
               /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/
```

I also removed the `$$PWD/../..` parts from the other paths I had set in my `.pro` file.

After making these changes, my code began running properly.

Comment: "Super User" (https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) offers more support on matters related to environment variables and setting paths.